# Convert ms timestamp to NSString date

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate

I know a lot of iOS conversion questions have been asked before but I just can't find a way to solve my problem.

I'd like to convert a milliseconds timestamp (i.e. 1299970800) to a correct, human readable date,  but how?

Something like "12 Mar 2011" is enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(ms / 1000)];
```

assuming `ms` holds the number of milliseconds since [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) in an integer or long.

Comment: thanks but I noticed my problem came from int vs. long values. I had to convert my ms timestamp into a long instead of an int to get it working. Duh! [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([msTimestampString longLongValue]/1000)];

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];
then use seconds, minutes and hours as shown in the below code snippet to get readable date.

[Readable Date for iOS](http://technoloz.com/blog/readable-date-in-objective-c-for-ios-and-mac-os-x/)